# Python: How to make Pillow and Tkinter compatible?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to run some Python code that uses both tkinter and Pillow. When I run the code in my IDE (Pycharm), the program opens and there are no issues. However, when I try to the run the code on its own as a Python file, I get a quick flash of the Command prompt which immediately shuts down. Im running Python 3.7.0 (latest version), which means I also have the latest version of tkinter, as well as Pillow 5.2.0. How do I get my code to run with its UI as a standalone python file?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

mapFrame=Frame(root)
mapFrame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.85, relwidth=1)
subMapFrame = Frame(mapFrame)
subMapFrame.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.9)

image = Image.open("field.png")
img_copy= image.copy()
background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
background = Label(subMapFrame, image=background_image)
background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the end of your python file.

`input('Press any key to exit')`

It will prevent the Command prompt close immediately unless you press some keys.

Comment: I tried adding the line of code before, and then after the root.mainloop line. Still can't open the UI.

Comment: @KeenanB Can you define width and height in `mapFrame=Frame(root)` ?

Comment: I tried changing both frames so that the width and height were defined as such: mapFrame=Frame(root,width=150,height=150) 
mapFrame.place(x=0, y=0) 
subMapFrame = Frame(mapFrame, width=100, height=100) 
subMapFrame.place(x=0,y=0)

Comment: Have you check the image is existed or not. Since if I changed the image path to sth not existing, the prompt closed immediately.

Comment: Yup. When I run the code in my IDE (Pycharm) it works, the UI shows up, and the image inside the UI. It’s only when I try to run the code as a .py file through python that the UI won’t load.

Comment: When you double click and run, you are running it via python installed on your pc instead of pycharm. You need to pip install pillow for your python too. A good way to check is to right click on the py file, click edit by ide, and run it.